# run scripts parallely

Tags: bash, etl

I have three shell scripts `a.sh`, `b.sh` and `c.sh`. I need to execute them simultaneously but with one condition that if `a.sh` gets completed then only `b.sh` and `c.sh` will execute. Script `a.sh` execution time varies.

I am calling Oracle procedure from the scripts on daily basis.

Comment: If you really want some another tool, then this question will be probably closed. Please clarify.

Answer (score 1):

Runs `a.sh` and if successful, runs `b.sh` and `c.sh` simultaneously and waits for both to complete.

```
./a.sh && (./b.sh & ./c.sh & wait)
```